# How can I use fillna for a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, function, categories, fillna

I already know how to use [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) but it fills every empty value with the same indicated value. In this case, I want to fill each empty value with different values, should I use the row number or how can it be done?

[image]

**Failed try**:

[image]

I want it to be

bmw 320i               2
plymouth reliant       1
honda civic            3

Comment: Can you please show the complete script you used to set up the data frame? This will help clarify your question, see [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition is not mentioned, the best solution I can provide is to use [mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).

It replaces values where the condition is True.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be bmw 320i 2 plymouth reliant 1 honda civic 3

You can fill the NaN in the first column with values from a series like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, "bmw 320i"],
                   [np.nan, "plymouth reliant"],
                   [np.nan, "honda civic"]],
                  columns=("origin", "car name"))
df2 = pd.Series([2,1,3]).to_frame(name="values")
df['origin'].fillna(value=df2["values"], inplace=True)
```